# SQL Server 2005 execution plan problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Currently, I found one query in our application and its execution plan is "index scan".Well, here are some background:

1. it has three columns and typed as "idType:bigint"
2. there is only 200 blew items in hand
3. there columns(a:PK, b:FK, c:FK), and we have two index (one clustered index(b,c), one PK non-clustered index (a))

Here is our query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select b,a from table where b in (@P0, @P1, @P2,
     @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8, @P9)',
     N'@P0 bigint, @P1 bigint, @P2 bigint, @P3 bigint, @P4 bigint, @P5 bigint,
       @P6 bigint, @P7 bigint, @P8 bigint, @P9 bigint', 
     94, 161, 4, 50, 166, 52, 53, 90, 100, 123
```

It shows from the execution plan as "index scan" on pk index...what's wrong?

And if I use the same query but not use "sp_executesql" like :

```
select b,a from table where b in(94,161,4,50,166,52,53,90,100,123)
```

It shows "clustered index seek" as I expected

Why will SQL Server use "index scan" for the first query? Does it relate to the function
"sp_executesql" itself?

Thank you in adv
Vance

Comment: Actual `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements are a lot easier to understand than descriptions (general caveat: provided you remove extraneous columns, if your tables are wide, and the problem can be demonstrated with a subset of the columns)

Comment: Try executing the code in a stored procedure, it would be interesting to see if the execution plan is the same as the sp_execute or T-SQL plan. (this is not necessarily a solution to your problem, I'm just trying to get more information)

Comment: Thank you all for the reply! @Tony I'm putting the first query 'exec sp_executesql N'...) in a SP and get the "index_scan" as same. Does this problem relates to my testing tables value is small? I've got only round 200 items in it, so will sql server do not "optimized" its query execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the execution plans of similar queries in my own database and can see a difference but I cannot fully explain it; I just thought my findings might be useful.

The difference seems to be due to the use of parameters on the compiled query.

*In the examples below I am using a table called [Resource] from a database I have, you will have to change the names for your queries.*

As you have found executing the query directly in management studio results in an index seek

[image: T_SQL Query]

Using the version with parameters gives a scan

[image]

If you fully prepare the statement and then pass it to the datbase, e.g.

```
exec('select id from [Resource] where id in (1,5,7,9,10)')
```

you get an index seek again

[image]

What is interesting is to look at the cached plans

```
SELECT cp.objtype,cp.usecounts,q.TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
 cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) p
 cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS q
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = 'Compiled Plan'
```

Which for the three statements executed I get

```
objtype   usecounts text
-------   --------- ----
Adhoc     1         select id from [Resource] where id in (1,5,7,9,10)
Prepared  1         (@p1 int, @p2 int, @p3 int, @p4 int, @p5 int)select id from [Resource] where id in (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)
Adhoc     1         select id from [Resource] where id in (1,5,7,9,10)
```

As you can see the SQL is quite different. Unfortunately that is as far as I can get to explain the difference in index selection you are seeing. Perhaps someone else can take this further?

**EDIT 1:** I have read some more it comes down to the optimiser having to create a plan to satisfy all possible parameter values (as Kragen has said in his answer).

I found the same information in this article: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)

**EDIT 2:** In response to Martin's comment, here is the execution plan of his SQL statement

[image]

Comment: I'd imagine it comes down to selectivity. What if you get the 5 ids from here `select top (5) id, COUNT(*) from [Resource] group by id order by COUNT(*) desc` and try them as literals do you get a scan or a seek?

Comment: @Martin: I posted the query but I think I have misunderstood what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Yep you have! Suppose your query showed that the 5 most common ids were `100,101,102,103,104` I was wondering what plan you would get for `select id from [Resource] where id in (100,101,102,103,104)` if that still gave you a plan with a seek then I can think of no justification at all for the parameterised version giving a scan as this should be the worst case.

Comment: @Martin - Ok, I see what you are saying. I did try `select id from [Resource] where id in (1,5,7,9,10)` (see the first execution plan image) which does a seek. I am using some data to test the queries and it isn't the same as the data VanceZhao has.

Comment: Actually we use ibatis and the above query with parameters is generated from it. Yes, the 'select id from [Resource] where id in (1,5,7,9,10)' will does a seek and also get seek under 'select id from [Resource] where id in(@a,@a,@a)' But really get scan on query 'select id from [Resource] where id in(@a,@b,@c)

Answer (score 1):

The difference may be due to a cached query plan executed at a time when different data or different parameters meant that a table scan / index seek was appropriate. (The SQL command text itself is different and so they will both have different entries in the plan cache).  If you want to test this you can clear the plan cache using this command:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE -- Don't run me on a production SQL server!
```

Then try running both commands again and see if there is still a difference (there are versions of the above command that are production safe if you are willing to dig through the plan cache)

Note that **a table scan is not always a bad thing** - especially when the table is narrow and there aren't many rows (which looks to be the case in your example).  In this case a table scan can be far more efficient than an index seek.